# ASP. NET MVC3 - How to display all Comments in Post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am a beginner ASP.net, I want to display all comment in post. Detail() method in PostController only shows post content, I don't know how to handle Detail() method to show commnent in post.

Hope someone can help me, Thank so much.

I have two model

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string Content{ get; set; }

}
public class Comment
{
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

and this is Post Controller

```
public class PostController : Controller
{
   //////
     public ViewResult Detail(int id )
     {
        Post viewpost= (repository.Posts.Single(p => p.PostID == id));

        return View(viewpost);
     }
    ////////////////
}
```

Comment: what you actually want?you want to display content in view or anything else?

Comment: I want show all comments relates Post(Topic). (sorry I used the word is not exactly). (Post = Topic = Theard)

Comment: What are you using for your data layer?  EF, Linq2Sql?  Is your repository an abstraction around that?

Comment: I used EF.
  public class EFPostRepository : IPostRepository
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        public IQueryable<Post> Posts
        {
            get { return context.Posts; }
        }
    }

Comment: So yes, as Mortalus said, you should have a navigation property for scenarios like this.  It would then automatically do the join for you.  How are you storing your Comments?  Aren't they getting added to the repository?  What property are they getting added/inserted to?

Comment: @nisun if you have solved the question with one of the answers here, be sure to select that as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moralus has a good answer.  If you don't want to change your Post model to have a navigation property to its comments, if out of your control or something, then you would have to make something like a ViewPostModel

```
public class ViewPostModel
{
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you would have to query your repository for both lists:

```
public class PostController : Controller
{
     public ViewResult Detail(int id )
     {
        ViewPostModel viewpost = new ViewPostModel();
        viewPost.Post = repository.Posts.Single(p => p.PostID == id);
        viewPost.Comments = repository.Comments.Where(c=> c.PostID = id).ToList();
        return View(viewpost);
     }
}
```

Comment: That was assuming that your repository has a property for comments, since you didn't give any code related to that.  If you're not storing your comments, then you can't get them.  So to get them, you'd go to the repository, to a property I'd assume would be named Comments.  That is if you have not specified navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you should have a navigation property from post to it's comment.
something like this:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string Content{ get; set; }

    public virtual IEnummrable<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
}
```

Note that if your using DB-First to do that you should edit EDMX

Then just take the comments from the repository like that:

```
public ViewResult Detail(int id )
{
   Post viewpost= (repository.Posts.Include("Comments").Single(p => p.PostID == id));
   return View(viewpost);
}
```

And in your view iterate trought your comments and display them like that

```
@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
{
    @comment.Content
}
```

**EDIT:**
All of the above is relevant only if you use EF\ Linq-2-SQL (thanks @tostringtheory)

Comment: That is if it is EF, which he hasn't stated.  Linq-2-SQL still has navigation properties though.  Also, if EF, then `Include()` is caps.  Last, if the model was genned from a db, then make sure the db has a FK relation, because that would have genned the navigation property for you.

Comment: Posts.include(). Include() method not exist.

Comment: @nisun.  The Include() extension method is in the EntityFramework assembly, so if it isn't being referenced, you would have to add that reference.  also, the file would need a using directive for System.Data.Entity to bring Include() into scope.  Note that the little refactor/add using menu doesn't work for extension methods.  However, I really would try to do something else rather than add EF to your web project.

Comment: Thanks you, Mortalus. have a nice day.

Comment: @Mortalus, one extra thing I would add.  I don't know if you've seen it, but when using EF, you no longer have to Include with the 'magic string' specifying what you want.  You can now use Lambda expressions to specify the path and EF will parse out the string for you at run time.  That way if you ever change a property name, you have instant feedback that it wont work!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the ViewData put the comments to the View.

eg:
Action:
ViewData["Comments"] = repository.Comments.Where(c=> c.PostID = id).ToList();

View:
var comments =ViewData["Comments"] as List;
...and you can use the var-comments